# How to format "time with time zone" in Postgres?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, time, formatting

I have a database field of type `time with time zone`.  How can I query this field in EST5EDT time zone with the output format hh:mm:ss?

All I can find is using multiple calls to `EXTRACT`:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIME WITH TIME ZONE '20:38:40-07' AT TIME ZONE 'EST5EDT');
```

*[Edit:]*

To be clear, this query:

```
SELECT TIME WITH TIME ZONE '20:38:40.001-07' AT TIME ZONE 'EST5EDT';
```

Returns "22:38:40.001" but I just want "22:38:40" as the output.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [TO_CHAR()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-formatting.html) function:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(date '2001-09-28' +time, 'HH24:MI:SS')
```

Seeing that TO_CHAR only accepts the timestamp datatype, you need to concatentate an arbitrary date value to your time value.

Comment: That's what I thought of before, but that only works with timestamps, not time: "ERROR: function to_char(time with time zone, unknown) does not exist".

Comment: You can test this like so: SELECT TO_CHAR(TIME WITH TIME ZONE '20:38:40.001-07', 'HH24:MI:SS')

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3 and this is no longer needed, now to_char() would work just fine with 'time without timezone' (or with timezone) data types.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

"time with time zone" is basically a bogus datatype, and as such isn't really supported in a lot of cases.

How do you define "time with time zone"? Time zones are dependent on dates, which aren't included in the datatype, and thus it's not fully defined. (yes, it's mandatory by the SQL standard, but that doesn't make it sane)

You're probably best off first fixing what datatype you're using. Either use timestamp with time zone, or use time (without time zone).

Comment: +1 That's a good perspective.  I may switch over to using time without time zones and make my life easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use CAST and CAST to the time type:

```
SELECT CAST(now() AS TIME)
```

(Of course, the result will have a different data type)

Comment: Thanks.  But how can I make the format hh:mm:ss?  Your output still has milliseconds.